# What happen if you already have an App on appstore but you lost the private key and revoke your old certificate?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Will your app stop  working?

I often want to start over. So I revoke all certificate. And then I delete everything related to development on my keychain.

Revoking certificate is useful because xcode will simply create another one.

Then I wonder. Will my old app stop working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't stop working, but the APNs certificates will have to recreated in order for push notifications to work again since they'll stop working, because they are bound to a certain production certificate.

Comment: even if you revoke the old certificate?